# element not retaining the final value after animation

Tags: html, css

Look at the css below. `bottom:0` doesn't get applied at all  once the animation is over

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

div:empty {

    -webkit-animation: mymoveClose 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymoveClose 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {bottom: -30px;}
    to {bottom: 0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    from {bottom: -30px;}
    to {bottom: 0px;}
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymoveClose {
    from {bottom: 0px;}
    to {bottom: -30px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymoveClose {
    from {bottom: 0px;}
    to {bottom: -30px;}
}
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/uk4gxr8c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an `animation-fill-mode`.

In this case `forwards` will cause the animation to end at the final value.

Per [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe encountered depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '';
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-animation: mymoveClose 1s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymoveClose 1s linear forwards;
}
div:empty {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 1s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 1s linear forwards;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    bottom: -30px;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    bottom: -30px;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymoveClose {
  from {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  to {
    bottom: -30px;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymoveClose {
  from {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  to {
    bottom: -30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">linear</div>
```

Comment: could u suggest how do i change this to a transform  instead of bottom as i hear it's performance is better

Comment: Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/uk4gxr8c/3/